# Process in Pipe which Processes 256 bytes at a Time

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs, mkfifo

I have a c program on a Cyclone 5 that does an FFT using the connected FPGA. This program currently takes 256 bytes from `stdin` and then process it gives the FFT results on `stdout`. I run it like this from the Linux bash on the Cyclone 5.

```
./fpga_fft < input_s16le_audio.pcm
```

This only evaluates the first 256 bytes. How do I do this, so that the program is continuously called with the stdin stream until all from the *.pcm file is read?

Ideas:

```
cat input_s16le_audio.pcm|xargs ./fpga_fft
```

Somehow xargs needs to be told to process 256 bytes at the time in chronological sequential order (not parallel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for i in {0..N} 
do
    dd if=input_s16le_audio.pcm bs=256 count=1 skip=$i |  ./fpga_fft
done
```

Obviously you have to replace the for loop by something that stops when the whole file has been processed (when the skip value is too big, dd just sends 0 bytes, so you cannot count on a bad rc).

Now, if you have a C program, it should be that hard to change it to make it loop on its input file?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
cat input_s16le_audio.pcm |
  parallel --pipe --recend '' --block 256 ./fpga_fft
```

If multiple `fpga_fft` cannot run in parallel, add `-j0`